# Plotting two data lines together in J

Tags: j

I have a sequence of data, and can easily use plot in J to show it:

```
data1 =: 0  0.7  1  0.7  0 _0.7 _1 _0.7  0  0.7
plot data1
```

However, if I have another set of data:

```
 data2 =:  0.7  0 _0.7 _1 _0.7  0  0.7 1 0.7 0
```

How do I display both plots together, e.g. (these obviously don't work):

```
 plot data1 data2
 plot data1 ; data2
```

And this one doesn't work either, but instead treats the data as two dimensional:

```
 plot (data1 ; data2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple data can be plot together by arranging them in a table. eg:

```
data1,:data2
0 0.7    1 0.7    0 _0.7  _1 _0.7   0 0.7
0.7   0 _0.7  _1 _0.7    0 0.7    1 0.7   0
plot data1,:data2
```

Take a look at the [plot wiki](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Plot)

Another way is to use `pd` utility

```
pd'new'
pd data1
pd data2
pd 'show'
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Just what I was looking for.